# Commerce Order id as seletion list in view filter and limit to 10

Tags: commerce, views

I am trying to make Order id as selection list exposed filter but couldn't make it possible.
I modified default order view by making clone, added block to view.This view block will be presented to the authenticated user where he can view his/her last 10 orders.

In views sort criteria order date is added which is in descending so that only most recent orders are fetched
Pager setting  - Use pager: Display a specified number of items | 10 items

Order's details has to be shown when user selects any order no from select list.
Is it possible to make selection list of Order id?Is there any module for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in [views](https://drupal.org/project/views).

- Add a new view for the product display type.
- Add a relationship under "Advanced -> RELATIONSHIP" with the product, something like "Content: Referenced product", check "Require this relationship".
- Add a filter in "FILTER CRITERIA" & choose "Commerce Product: Product ID" by help of added relationship, expose this filter.
- Show it wherever you want, like you can make tab in the profile page etc.

Comment: I dont understand why relationship is necessary here.I cloned the existing view(commerce_user_orders) which is working fine.All I need to do is add Expose filter of ORDER IDs which should be rendered as selection list rather than autocomplete, limited to last 10 orders of user.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using the [Views Selective Filters](http://drupal.org/project/views_selective_filters) module.

- Install the module.
- Add the field to Filters using the (selective) version.
- And there you go.